# Transition from darkened image to non-darkened on mouse over with CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, hover, fadeout, mouseout

I´m trying to get the inverse effect of this code ([jsfiddle-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/35mghwu7/)):

```
a.darken {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
}

a.darken img {
    display: block;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.7;    
}

div.hoverText{display = none;}
```

I mean, I want a html code where its images are darkened and the darkeness disappears «on mouse over» -with a transition.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to invert the opacity values :)
(the "base" background must have opacity < 1, and the ":hovered" background must have opacity = 1)
Here's a fork of you fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m1mcb66h/

```
a.darken img {
  [...]
  opacity: 0.7;
}
a.darken:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted and it has helped me to understanding the logic of the code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

instead of

```
opacity:0.7;
```

write

```
filter: contrast(150%);
```

Comment: Thank you, very nice effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your .html is as follows:

```
<a class='darken'><img src='image1.jpg'></a>
<a class='darken'><img src='image2.jpg'></a>
```

I solved it like this:

```
    a.darken {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
}

a.darken img{
    display: block;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

div.hoverText{display = none;}
```

Your last pseudoclass works fine also like this:

```
    a.darken img:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Please, provide .html for future questions.